# How to get states of services in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu with  upstart & System-V services.
I need to gather in one script: services status (started/stopped) and next boot status (will/wouldn't start on boot)

chkconfig not works for my case:

```
# chkconfig --list|grep lxc
#
# initctl list|grep lxc
shoc-lxc-net stop/waiting
```

I wrote script, which is cheeking services status and output like json. But i can't find how check if service will boot: for upstart + system V.

```
#!/bin/bash
###############
# gether status of services:
#   output json/plain text
#   init.d & upstart
# weldpua2008@gmail.com
################
SERVICE=
SERVICEDIR="/etc/init.d"
SUDO=""
JSON_OUTPUT="true"
ONLYONESERVICE="false"
usage(){
        cat << EOL
        USAGE:
           $0 -j yes to enable json output [ by default ]
          -s yes  enable sudo [ not used by default ]
          -n servicename (if you want view status of service)

EOL
exit 1
}

##############################################
# program part
#
unset SELECTIVE_SERVICES_STATUS
declare -A SELECTIVE_SERVICES_STATUS
STATUS="?"

while getopts "n:s:j:" option ;do
     case $option in
         j) if [[ $OPTARG == "true" || $OPTARG == "yes" ]];then
                JSON_OUTPUT="true"
            else
                JSON_OUTPUT="false"
                fi
            ;;

         n) ONLYONESERVICE="true"
            ONE_SERVICE=$OPTARG
            SELECTIVE_SERVICES_STATUS[$ONE_SERVICE]="?";
            ;;
            # to use sudo
         s) SUDO=`which sudo`
             ;;
        \?) usage
            exit 1
            ;;
         :) usage
            exit 1
            ;;
     esac
done

# output for one service option
function output_one_service() {
    local COMMA=$1
     case "${STATUS}" in
        "?") out_state="unknown";;
        "+")out_state="started";;
        "-")out_state="stopped";;
     esac

    if [ ${JSON_OUTPUT} == "true" ];then
        echo "${COMMA}{ \"name\":\"${SERVICE}\", "
        echo "  \"state\": \"${out_state}\""
        echo "}"
    else
         echo "${SERVICE} ${out_state}"
    fi
}




#############################################
# Changing global variable STATUS with ?/+/-
#############################################
function upstart_get_status(){
    STATUS="?"
    ${SUDO} initctl status $SERVICE 2> /dev/null|grep start &> /dev/null 
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        STATUS="+"
    fi
    ${SUDO} initctl status $SERVICE 2> /dev/null|grep stop &> /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        STATUS="-"
    fi
}

#############################################
# Changing global variable STATUS with ?/+/-
#############################################
function system5_get_status(){

    STATUS="?"
    # TODO: need implement service status
    if [ -x "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ]; then
        if ! ${SUDO} grep -qs "\Wstatus)" "${SERVICEDIR}/$SERVICE"; then
                          #printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[?]" "$SERVICE:" "unknown" 1>&2
                          #echo "? $SERVICE" 
              STATUS="?"
                      #    continue
        else
            out=$(env -i LANG="$LANG" PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "${SUDO} $SERVICEDIR/$SERVICE" status 2>&1)
                if [ "$?" = "0" -a -n "$out" ]; then
                            #printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[+]" "$SERVICE:" "running"
                            #echo "+ $SERVICE"
                    STATUS="+"
                          #  continue
                 else
                            #printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[-]" "$SERVICE:" "NOT running"
                            #echo "- $SERVICE"
                    STATUS="-"                   
                 fi
        fi       

        out_temp=`${SUDO} service  ${SERVICE} status 2>/dev/null |grep -v "Usage:" |grep -v  "usage:"`
        echo "${out_temp}"| grep -w 'is not running\|is NOT running' &> /dev/null
         if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
            STATUS="-"
        fi

        echo "${out_temp}"| grep -w 'start/running\|is running\|is up and running\|* running\|* running.'  &> /dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
            STATUS="+"
        fi        
        #echo "service  ${SERVICE} status ${STATUS}"
    fi
}


# only if -n was provided
if [ ${ONLYONESERVICE} == "true" ];then
    if [ ${JSON_OUTPUT} == "true" ];then echo "["; fi
    COMMA=""
    for SERVICE in "${!SELECTIVE_SERVICES_STATUS[@]}";do
        upstart_get_status
        if [ "${STATUS}" == "?" ];then
           system5_get_status
        fi
        SELECTIVE_SERVICES_STATUS[$ONE_SERVICE]=${STATUS}   
        output_one_service ${COMMA}
        COMMA=","
    done
     if [ ${JSON_OUTPUT} == "true" ];then echo "]"; fi
    exit 0
fi


SERVICES_LIST=` ${SUDO} find ${SERVICEDIR}  -type f  -printf "%f\n" |grep -Ev "skeleton|README|*.dpkg-dist|*.dpkg-old|rc|rcS|single|reboot|bootclean.sh|functions|halt|killall|single|linuxconf|kudzu|.legacy-bootordering"`
unset GLOBAL_STATUS
declare -A GLOBAL_STATUS
for SERVICE in ${SERVICES_LIST} ; do
    system5_get_status
    GLOBAL_STATUS[$SERVICE]=${STATUS}
#   echo ">$SERVICE ${GLOBAL_STATUS[$SERVICE]}"
done
for SERVICE in `${SUDO} initctl list|cut -d " " -f1|uniq`;do
    upstart_get_status
    SERVICE_NAME=`echo $SERVICE|cut -d  " " -f1`
    # check if key exist
    if [ "${STATUS}" != "?" ];then
        GLOBAL_STATUS[$SERVICE_NAME]=${STATUS}
        ###############################
        # TODO:
        # this logic don't work. Seams we must 
        #       gather status throw service status,
        #       and not with: /etc/init.d/{service} status
        # #######################################
        #if [ ${GLOBAL_STATUS[${SERVICE_NAME}]+abc} ];then 
        #   if [ ${GLOBAL_STATUS[${SERVICE_NAME}]} == "?" ];then
        #       GLOBAL_STATUS[$SERVICE_NAME]=${STATUS}
        #   fi
        #else
        #    GLOBAL_STATUS[$SERVICE_NAME]=${STATUS}
        #fi
    fi
done

START=""
STOP=""
UNKNOWN=""
for SERVICE_NAME in "${!GLOBAL_STATUS[@]}";do
    if [ ${JSON_OUTPUT} == "true" ];then
        if [ ${GLOBAL_STATUS[${SERVICE_NAME}]} == "+" ];then
            START="${START}, \"${SERVICE_NAME}\":{\"current_state\":\"started\"} "
        elif [ ${GLOBAL_STATUS[${SERVICE_NAME}]} == "-" ];then
            STOP="${STOP}, \"${SERVICE_NAME}\":{\"current_state\":\"stopped\"}"
        else 
            UNKNOWN="${UNKNOWN}, \"${SERVICE_NAME}\":{\"current_state\":\"unknown\"}"
        fi
    else
        echo "${SERVICE_NAME} ${GLOBAL_STATUS[${SERVICE_NAME}]}"
    fi
done
if [ ${JSON_OUTPUT} == "true" ];then
    echo "{ \"services\":"
    echo "  {"

    # started services
    echo "      \"start\": {"
    echo ${START:1}
    echo "      },"
    echo "      \"stop\": {"
    echo ${STOP:1}
    echo "      },"
      echo "      \"unknown\": {"
    echo ${UNKNOWN:1}
    echo "      }"


    echo "  }"
    #
    echo "}"

fi

cd ${OLDPWD}
exit 0
```

PS:

Sorry for my English